# Attempting to read line from file returns incorrect line

Tags: c, file, io

When reading a line from a file in C it returns the wrong line when attempting to use printf. I assume this is because I am returning char* rather than char however returning char causes a crash.

```
char* getLineFromFile(const char name[], int lineNumber) 
{
    FILE *file = fopen(name, "r");
    int count = 0;
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {
            if (count == lineNumber)
            {
                fclose(file);
                return line;
            }
            else
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Couldn't find file!");
    }
}

//Example call
printf(getLineFromFile("Include/index.db", 1));
```

Should get second line of file but returns malformed string instead.

Comment: Did you forget to return something in the case of fallthrough. Also you need to malloc the buffer since it is not possible to return a pointer to local variable

Comment: Furthermore you must **never** use printf like this - just try what will happen if the line contains `%n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `return line;` in `getLineFromFile` - you're returning a [local array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) and invoking undefined behavior when you attempt to access it by calling `printf`. Instead, pass a buffer to `getLineFromFile` and copy into it when you find your line:

```
int getLineFromFile(const char name[], int lineNumber, char* out, size_t outsize)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(name, "r");
    int count = 0;
    if (file != NULL)
    {
        char line[256]; /* or other suitable maximum line size */
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL) /* read a line */
        {
            if (count == lineNumber)
            {
                fclose(file);
                strncpy(out, line, outsize);
                out[outsize - 1] = '\0';
                return 1;
            }   
            else
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        fclose(file);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Couldn't find file!");
        return 0;
    }
}

//Example call
char lineBuffer[256];
if (getLineFromFile("Include/index.db", 1, lineBuffer, sizeof lineBuffer)) {
    printf("%s", lineBuffer);
}
```